# General knowledge question regarding classes and class instances in C++

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I'll start with my problem:
My problem is that I'm getting a segmentation fault when I try to access a `public` function within an instance within a class.

Suppose I have a class `A` that has a bunch of class instances in it like so:

```
class A {
      ...

    public:
        class B *B;
        class C *C;

};
```

Let's consider class `A` to be our "global" class; that is, class `A` is sent to every class that I initialize and own. Therefore, every class function can call functions from class `A` through `A->function()`. Furthermore, assuming other instances have been initialized, every class can call functions of instances belonging to `A`, like so: `A->B->function()`. Up to now, everything worked great. My problem is that I'm suddenly getting a segfault when trying to access a function of one of the instances belonging to `A`. What I think the reason is (and why I am asking this question, because I am unsure), is that the class instance `A` is sent to class `C` before instance `B` has been initialized. Then in class `C`, I simply create a pointer copy (meaning my class `C` has a private instance of `A` called `class A *A`). So then when I first create an instance of class `C`, I send it class `A` and all of it's public members, which `C`'s constructor then makes the local copy of `A`.

Phew. That was difficult to do without presenting code. So here's the question; say one of my class `A` functions contains:

```
C *c = new C(this);
```

and the constructor for `C` has this:

```
C(A *a_val) { a = a_val; }
```

while also containing a private instance-pointer `class A *a;`

then another function in `A` instantiates the `B` class. Would my `C` class be able to use that `B` class? And if not (which is why I think I'm segfaulting), how could I possibly solve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry I can't provide actual code. It's just very lengthy and I don't think pasting hundreds of lines here is necessary.

Comment: Is it really necessary to have such interdependencies between A, B and C? I suspect your problem will disappear with some thought and refactoring. Also, it's difficult to envisage your problem without code. How about writing a small test program to post here?

Comment: You probably have an issue with the order that members are being initialized, but it isn't clear without a more detailed example.

Comment: Its probably worth spending the time to produce a reduced chunk of code that reproduces the problem. (There's even a good chance you'll find your problem as you create your example)

Comment: I'll try to work on a small chunk of code to reproduce the situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general your code will segfault if you dereference a pointer to an unitialized variable. From your description, this sounds like what is happening, although it's hard to tell given the lack of an example that fails.

> another function in A instantiates the B class. Would my C class be
>   able to use that B class?

Yes. This should work provided you instantianted correctly and passed the pointer to B correctly to C. Also note that it would help to get the terminology a bit more correct in the above question:

*another function in A instantiates an object of the the B class. Would my C object be
able to use that B object?*

I believe the above is what your question really meant to say.

Comment: how about if I passed the pointer of `A` to `C` before `B` was instantiated, but I only used something like `A->B->function()` *after* `B` was instantiated (without repassing the pointer)? Is that still okay?

Comment: @Amit yeah if you do that after an object of type B is  instantiated and you tell A about this new object, then things should be ok. It's hard to tell what you're trying to do though from your descriptions.

Comment: so if `A` knows of this new `B` object, and a pointer of `A` was sent to `C` before `B` was instantiated, `C` will still be able to use `B`? Am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: you were very helpful actually. I realized `B` wasn't fully 'constructed'. That is, I had a function in it's constructor that prevented it from completing the scope of the constructor, and had tried to use the `B` instance before it being completely constructed. Thanks a lot!